# Magento Create attribute with Data type Varchar(100)

Tags: magento-1.9, database, attributes, ce-1.9.2.4

I have created a customer attribute using installer script. Attribute gets created but what **I want is by default magento is setting `varchar(255)` but I want the `varchar(100)`**

I have used below code:

```
$attribute = array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Company name',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 0,
    'position' => 132

);
$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'company_name', $attribute);
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
        ->getAttribute('customer', 'company_name')
        ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer'))
        ->save();
```

Can anyone suggest, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

you cannot.
Attributes of type `varchar` are kept in the table `customer_entity_varchar` table and their values are stored in the column `value` that has type `VARCHAR(255)`.